# Override IDENTITY constraint when table is copied

Tags: sql-server

I have two databases: A and B.

I have a .dtsx job using a "Transfer SQL Server Objects Task Editor" to copy tables from A to B.  This is not a script; It looks like the attached image.

One of the tables has an IDENTITY column defined like this: `SOMEID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL`.

It appears (but I have not been able to confirm yet), that when the table is copied from A to B that the SOMEID column is rewritten so the SOMEID values do not match between A and B for the same record.

The table does not exist on B when the copy begins.

Does that make sense?

How can I force them to match when the table is copied?  ( I need answer in the context of the GUI I am using, not a script ).

Please excuse my description as I am not a Windows developer so it is difficult for me to google for the answer because I don't know the correct terminology.

[image]

Comment: The second table should not have an identity column if it is getting data from the first table.

Comment: You'll have to show the script that the package is using when it generates and populates the table on B. If it just does an insert without using SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON then, no, there is no guarantee that you will get the same IDENTITY values for any given row.

Comment: I suppose you can use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` in the destination table. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is a checkbox in OleDBDestination (prefered by performance reasons) to set identity insert ON. Simply check it and the id column will be written to destination

Answer (score 0):

You need to set identity inserts on, with this SQL:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have been using something like the below:

```
set identity_insert [USI_MD_TEMP].[dbo].[CS-DISCOUNT EXTID] on

INSERT INTO [USI_MD_TEMP].[dbo].[CS-DISCOUNT EXTID] ([key], [disExtID])
SELECT [Copy of key],[Copy of disExtID] 
FROM [USI_MD_TEMP].[dbo].[CS-DISCOUNT EXTID tmp]

set identity_insert [USI_MD_TEMP].[dbo].[CS-DISCOUNT EXTID] off
```

Here [key] is not a primary key.